# How does the algorithm to color the song list in iTunes 11 work?

Tags: algorithm, user-interface, itunes

The new iTunes 11 has a very nice view for the song list of an album, picking the colors for the fonts and background in function of album cover. Anyone figured out how the algorithm works?

[image: Third Example]

Comment: The w3c color contrast formula might be part of the answer.  My own empircal tests show that this formula is used by MS Word to decide it's auto-color font.

Search for "Color brightness is determined by the following formula"

[w3c color contrast formula][1]


  [1]: http://www.w3.org/TR/AERT#color-contrast

Comment: @bluedog , i think you are right. I tried a lot of my album covers and always the font has enough contrast with the background to watch it clearly.

Comment: Can be related with color quantization? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_quantization

Comment: Color quantization was my first thought too, but it's more subtle than that. I experimented last night and Billy Joel's River of Dreams album was enlightening - the background became a bright blue even though that particular shade is a very small part of the artwork. There was another album that had a red stripe across the top and that was the selected color, even though the majority of the background was something else - and a similar cover with a green top didn't pick the green.

Comment: Question updated with some data from basic experimentation. If you have suggestion for improve the question, please comment.

Comment: You might try various colors in different locations of the image. That might help figure out how it picks a background color and text colors.

Comment: There's an attempt to replicate the behaviour in Javascript here: http://fladdict.net/blog/2012/11/itunes11_colorpicker.html

Comment: Something else to note is that it seems to differ between Mac OS and Windows: https://twitter.com/grimfrog/status/275187988374380546

Comment: I could imagine that maybe not only the quantity of the colors, but also their saturation values are part of the calculation: My experiments led me to the conclusions, that highlight colors are often being picked as background color although they occur in few areas of the image.
That's why I believe looking at the histogram of the cover image and its **peaks** could be useful, and based on some finely tuned parameters, the color is chosen.

Comment: See another answer at http://www.panic.com/blog/2012/12/itunes-11-and-colors/

Comment: Nice to see you pirate your music... :(

Comment: There is also [this very interesting kmeans discussion](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4694663) on hackernews

Answer (score 424, accepted):

[image: Example 1]

I approximated the iTunes 11 color algorithm in Mathematica given the album cover as input:

[image: Output 1]

### How I did it

Through trial and error, I came up with an algorithm that works on ~80% of the albums with which I've tested it.

#### Color Differences

The bulk of the algorithm deals with finding the dominant color of an image.  A prerequisite to finding dominant colors, however, is calculating a quantifiable difference between two colors. One way to calculate the difference between two colors is to calculate their Euclidean distance in the RGB color space.  However, human color perception doesn't match up very well with distance in the RGB color space.

Therefore, I wrote a function to convert RGB colors (in the form `{1,1,1}`) to [YUV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV), a color space which is much better at approximating color perception:

<sub>(EDIT: [@cormullion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/933113/cormullion) and [@Drake](https://stackoverflow.com/users/261718/drake) pointed out that Mathematica's built-in CIELAB and CIELUV color spaces would be just as suitable... looks like I reinvented the wheel a bit here)</sub>

```js
convertToYUV[rawRGB_] :=
    Module[{yuv},
        yuv = {{0.299, 0.587, 0.114}, {-0.14713, -0.28886, 0.436},
            {0.615, -0.51499, -0.10001}};
        yuv . rawRGB
    ]
```

Next, I wrote a function to calculate color distance with the above conversion:

```js
ColorDistance[rawRGB1_, rawRGB2_] := 
    EuclideanDistance[convertToYUV @ rawRGB1, convertToYUV @ rawRGB2]
```

#### Dominant Colors

I quickly discovered that the built-in Mathematica function `DominantColors` doesn't allow enough fine-grained control to approximate the algorithm that iTunes uses.  I wrote my own function instead...

A simple method to calculate the dominant color in a group of pixels is to collect all pixels into buckets of similar colors and then find the largest bucket.

```js
DominantColorSimple[pixelArray_] :=
    Module[{buckets},
        buckets = Gather[pixelArray, ColorDistance[#1,#2] < .1 &];
        buckets = Sort[buckets, Length[#1] > Length[#2] &];
        RGBColor @@ Mean @ First @ buckets
    ]
```

<sub>Note that `.1` is the tolerance for how different colors must be to be considered separate.  Also note that although the input is an array of pixels in raw triplet form (`{{1,1,1},{0,0,0}}`), I return a Mathematica `RGBColor` element to better approximate the built-in `DominantColors` function.</sub>

My actual function `DominantColorsNew` adds the option of returning up to `n` dominant colors after filtering out a given other color.  It also exposes tolerances for each color comparison:

```js
DominantColorsNew[pixelArray_, threshold_: .1, n_: 1, 
    numThreshold_: .2, filterColor_: 0, filterThreshold_: .5] :=
    Module[
        {buckets, color, previous, output},
        buckets = Gather[pixelArray, ColorDistance[#1, #2] < threshold &];
        If[filterColor =!= 0, 
        buckets = 
            Select[buckets, 
                ColorDistance[ Mean[#1], filterColor] > filterThreshold &]];
        buckets = Sort[buckets, Length[#1] > Length[#2] &];
        If[Length @ buckets == 0, Return[{}]];
        color = Mean @ First @ buckets;
        buckets = Drop[buckets, 1];
        output = List[RGBColor @@ color];
        previous = color;
        Do[
            If[Length @ buckets == 0, Return[output]];
            While[
                ColorDistance[(color = Mean @ First @ buckets), previous] < 
                    numThreshold, 
                If[Length @ buckets != 0, buckets = Drop[buckets, 1], 
                    Return[output]]
            ];
            output = Append[output, RGBColor @@ color];
            previous = color,
            {i, n - 1}
        ];
        output
    ]
```

#### The Rest of the Algorithm

First I resized the album cover (`36px`, `36px`) & reduced detail with a bilateral filter

```js
image = Import["http://i.imgur.com/z2t8y.jpg"]
thumb = ImageResize[ image, 36, Resampling -> "Nearest"];
thumb = BilateralFilter[thumb, 1, .2, MaxIterations -> 2];
```

iTunes picks the background color by finding the dominant color along the edges of the album.  However, it ignores narrow album cover borders by cropping the image.

```js
thumb = ImageCrop[thumb, 34];
```

Next, I found the dominant color (with the new function above) along the outermost edge of the image with a default tolerance of `.1`.

```js
border = Flatten[
    Join[ImageData[thumb][[1 ;; 34 ;; 33]] , 
        Transpose @ ImageData[thumb][[All, 1 ;; 34 ;; 33]]], 1];
background = DominantColorsNew[border][[1]];
```

Lastly, I returned 2 dominant colors in the image as a whole, telling the function to filter out the background color as well.

```js
highlights = DominantColorsNew[Flatten[ImageData[thumb], 1], .1, 2, .2, 
    List @@ background, .5];
title = highlights[[1]];
songs = highlights[[2]];
```

<sub>The tolerance values above are as follows: `.1` is the minimum difference between "separate" colors; `.2` is the minimum difference between numerous dominant colors (A lower value might return black and dark gray, while a higher value ensures more diversity in the dominant colors); `.5` is the minimum difference between dominant colors and the background (A higher value will yield higher-contrast color combinations)</sub>

*Voila!*

```js
Graphics[{background, Disk[]}]
Graphics[{title, Disk[]}]
Graphics[{songs, Disk[]}]
```

[image: Final Output]

#### Notes

The algorithm can be applied very generally.  I tweaked the above settings and tolerance values to the point where they work to produce generally correct colors for ~80% of the  album covers I tested.  A few edge cases occur when `DominantColorsNew` doesn't find two colors to return for the highlights (i.e. when the album cover is monochrome).  My algorithm doesn't address these cases, but it would be trivial to duplicate iTunes' functionality: when the album yields less than two highlights, the title becomes white or black depending on the best contrast with the background.  Then the songs become the one highlight color if there is one, or the title color faded into the background a bit.

### More Examples

[image: More Examples]

Comment: OK @Seth Thompson, it seems very promising. I'm going to try it my self, it will take me a couple of days, please be patient.

Comment: Pretty awesome solution. Now need a port from Mathematica to  Objective-C, that is a hard struggle.

Comment: +1 for this very detailed answer!

Comment: Nice answer! Just curious, could you have used Mathematica's new LUV colour space instead of YUV?

Comment: @cormullion LUV (and LAB) both aim for perceptual uniformity.  However, I didn't find any explicit references to using euclidean distances in either color space.  My guess is that if nothing else, they would both be better than RGB.

Comment: @loretoparisi check my answer, i've started a project in github for iOS.

Comment: When I put this code into Mathematica 8 it shows the variable `filter` in the function `DominantColorsNew` as blue text, meaning it is not defined. When I changed `filter` to `filterColor` so as to match the function parameter it seems to work.   
Specifically I am talking about the snippets `If[filter =!= 0, ` and `ColorDistance[ Mean[#1], filter]` inside the `DominantColorsNew` function.

Also, it seems Mathematica 8 doesn't have a `MaxIterations` option for `BilateralFilter`.

Comment: @SethThompson - this is fantastic! What a detailed explanation. I'm curious -- what inspired you to delve into this to such a great extent?

Comment: @SethThompson You're right. CIELab is perfect fit to this, and it does use Euclidean distance to measure the color difference. Refer to [Lab color space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space#Perceptual_differences)

Comment: @yuval I found enough edge cases in iTunes that were handled surprisingly well by their algorithm that I decided it was worth an investigation!

Comment: @Drake you're right!  I don't know how I missed that when I was researching this.  Looks like I reinvented the wheel.  You could easily just use Mathematica's built-in `ToCIELABColor` function.

Comment: This is what I like to call a "Chuck Norris Answer"

Comment: Ladies and gentlemen, God has found Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 43):

With the answer of @Seth-thompson and the comment of @bluedog, I build a little Objective-C (Cocoa-Touch) project to generate color schemes in function of an image.

You can check the project at :

https://github.com/luisespinoza/LEColorPicker

For now, LEColorPicker is doing:

1. Image is scaled to 36x36 px (this reduce the compute time).
2. It generates a pixel array from the image.
3. Converts the pixel array to YUV space.
4. Gather colors as Seth Thompson's code does it.
5. The color's sets are sorted by count.
6. The algorithm select the three most dominant colors.
7. The most dominant is asigned as Background.
8. The second and third most dominants are tested using the w3c color contrast formula, to check if the colors has enought contrast with the background.
9. If one of the text colors don't pass the test, then is asigned to white or black, depending of the Y component.

That is for now, I will be checking the ColorTunes project (https://github.com/Dannvix/ColorTunes) and the Wade Cosgrove project for new features. Also I have some new ideas for improve the color scheme result.

[image: Screenshot_Mona]

Comment: +1 - Very cool stuff, and a great example of how algorithm development and application development can both be very interesting in their own right

Comment: +1 for checking the contrast.

Comment: Yeah cool but how are you rounding the hash values for each color? I think I could break this algorithm easily, by simply adding a little black and white "Explicit" logo in the bottom right, you are  really adding a focus for black and white.

Anyways, this algorithm would work better for clip-art based images, but if you have the image at 36x36 those fail cases will be made more rare by the anti-aliasing

Comment: One word: FANTASTIC!

Answer (score 16):

Wade Cosgrove of Panic wrote a [nice blog post](http://www.panic.com/blog/2012/12/itunes-11-and-colors/) describing his implementation of an algorithm that approximates the one in iTunes. It includes a sample implementation in Objective-C.

Answer (score 15):

You might also checkout [ColorTunes](https://github.com/Dannvix/ColorTunes) which is a HTML implementation of the Itunes album view which is using the MMCQ (median cut color quantization) algorithm.

Comment: yes I already check it. Sadly seems barely documented.

Comment: The important comment in ColorTunes is the reference to the (median cut quantization algorithm)[http://www.leptonica.com/papers/mediancut.pdf]. I just implemented this in python in about 2 hours just form the description in the paper, and prefer it to my implementation of Seth's algorithm above. I like the results a bit better, but most importantly it is quite a bit faster (of course, I could have implemented Seth's algorithm incorrectly).

Comment: @sh1ftst0rm do you have your python implementation on github or somewhere?  cheers

Comment: @Anentropic Sorry, I don't. It was part of a private project I was working on, and I haven't extracted it out at all. If I get a chance to, I'll try to post it somewhere, but it probably won't be anytime soon.

Answer (score 7):

I just wrote a JS library implementing roughly the same algorithm that the one described by [**@Seth**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13675803/880703). It is freely available on [github.com/arcanis/colibrijs](https://github.com/arcanis/colibrijs/), and on NPM as `colibrijs`.

Answer (score 5):

With @Seth's answer I implemented the algorithm to get the dominant color in the two lateral borders of a picture using PHP and Imagick.

https://gist.github.com/philix/5688064#file-simpleimage-php-L81

It's being used to fill the background of cover photos in http://festea.com.br

Answer (score 4):

I asked the same question in a different context and was pointed over to http://charlesleifer.com/blog/using-python-and-k-means-to-find-the-dominant-colors-in-images/ for a learning algorithm (k Means) that rougly does the same thing using random starting points in the image. That way, the algorithm finds dominant colors by itself.