# Color recoginition in iTunes?

Tags: algorithm, colors

When Selecting the Album View in iTunes and clicking on a cover art, iTunes expands a colored band, that matches the cover art. Interestingly, font colors and highlight colors are also chosen to create a good match to the cover. I am working on an algorithm that does the same, but did not come up with a good solution to automatically find dominant colors in an image. My best solution is to take the respective median values of r, g and b. Any better ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the algorithm to color the song list in iTunes 11 work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637892/how-does-the-algorithm-to-color-the-song-list-in-itunes-11-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an excellent blog post recently about [finding dominant colors in images by using k-means clustering](http://charlesleifer.com/blog/using-python-and-k-means-to-find-the-dominant-colors-in-images/).  I'm not sure how well it will apply to your situation, but it might be a great starting point.

Hope this helps!