# How to classify RGB images based on color?

Tags: image-processing, classification, rgb

For RGB images i split each one into R band G band and B band, then threshold each color band and took average of the three bands.Is this procedure wrong? As i am not getting correct results

What is the correct procedure to classify similar images with different colors based on their RGB values?so that i can get classes with different colored images

Thanks

Comment: Oh if only it were so simple! Getting the dominant color of an image is an interesting problem. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637892/how-does-the-algorithm-to-color-the-song-list-in-itunes-11-work

Answer (score 0):

The method is you described is not wrong, but there are more reliable ways. The difficulty with RGB is the response is complex when the intensity of the lighting changes. Instead I would convert the image to Lab colour space. I would then set a threshold on a & b to find the colours. You also need to make sure L has a minimum value since a and b are poorly defined for black colours.

If you are classifying images with multiple colours I would consider using two histograms of a and b and measuring the Euclidean distance between your test image and the training set.

Comment: Thanks.. I am classifying the scanned currency images and as they do not have multiple colors so its not necessary to find the Euclidean distance between test image and the training set right?

Comment: Maybe, it depends on how complex the colour variations are. I would try the simple threshold method first. It maybe good enough.