# Detect if colour beneath UIVisualEffectView is light

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uivisualeffectview

[image]

Because the UIImageView in the background is very light, you can't see the text in the foreground on top of the UIVisualEffectView. I want to detect whether the background is light or not and if so, change the text colour to something darker. How can I do this?

Comment: Checkout UIVibrancyEffect (https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIVibrancyEffect/index.html). It's intended to be used on top of a blur effect to make the test stand out more by dynamically changing the text color based on the background. In particular, this is a great answer related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24225231/482255

Answer (score 2):

To detect the dominant color of a UIView it takes two steps.  First is to capture the image data of the view as described here: [How to capture UIView to UIImage without loss of quality on retina display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334233/how-to-capture-uiview-to-uiimage-without-loss-of-quality-on-retina-display)

Second is to determine what the dominant color of the view is as described here:
[How does the algorithm to color the song list in iTunes 11 work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637892/how-does-the-algorithm-to-color-the-song-list-in-itunes-11-work)

And then make your adjustments based on the result.

Personally, I would simply use a dark text color for the light blur.  Or continue with the light text and use the dark blur effect.  Or set a tint color on a navigation bar.