# How to get background and text color from an image like Apple Music does with album artwork?

Tags: ios, image-processing, uiview, uiimageview

I noticed that when you view an album on Apple Music the background color of the view controller changes and the text color seems to always be a color that pops from the background and is also somehow in the image.

Does anybody know how this is done or have any ideas about how to do something like this?

Comment: You might be interested in the [vImage Histogram Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/vImage_histogram/index.html) or the [CIAreaHistogram](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIAreaHistogram) filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact you need to determine what are the main tints of your image.
You can do this by parsing the pixels of your image in order to get a weighted list of color buckets. Then you select two of them so they contrast each other.

You can find a lot of samples doing/teaching that on the internet.
And you can find sample codes doing a similar thing like this one:
https://github.com/timominous/TDImageColors

Edit: also look at the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13675803/5432134

Hope this helps ;)