# Why is GPUImage slower than CPU calculation when calculating average color of image?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimage, core-graphics, gpuimage

In my project I am trying to get the average color of a series of `UIImage` objects. So I implemented a category `UIImage(AverageColor)` to calculate the average color.

Here's how I do it with the `GPUImage` library:

```
- (void)averageColor:(void (^)(UIColor *))handler {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        GPUImagePicture *picture = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:self];
        GPUImageAverageColor *averageColorFilter = [GPUImageAverageColor new];
        [averageColorFilter setColorAverageProcessingFinishedBlock:^(CGFloat r, CGFloat g, CGFloat b, CGFloat a, CMTime frameTime) {
            UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:r green:g blue:b alpha:a];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                handler(color);
            });
        }];
    
        [picture addTarget:averageColorFilter];
        [picture useNextFrameForImageCapture];
        [picture processImage];
    });
}
```

I've also tried the approach (pure CPU one I think?) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5562246/3719276). Then I test these two methods with the same `UIImage` and log out the time used in each methods. And here's the result:

> cpu time: 0.102402
>
> gpu time: 0.414044

I am surprised that the CPU one runs much faster. So what's the problem here? Am I using `GPUImage` in a wrong way?

---

#### Edit:

The above result was got from iOS simulator. When testing on real device (iPhone6s) the difference is even greater:

> cpu time: 0.019034
>
> gpu time: 0.137635

Answer (score 0):

It's not the color averaging that's slow, it's because there's a large amount of overhead in the creation of a GPUImagePicture from a UIImage. Instantiating a GPUImagePicture from a UIImage currently requires a re-render of that image via Core Graphics into a texture and the upload of that to the GPU.

This is a slow process, and if you can I'd recommend creating a GPUImagePicture once and reusing it, or avoiding dealing with UIImages altogether (grabbing directly from the camera, working with raw bytes, etc.). I've been working on direct decoding of JPEG and PNG images to raw bytes within the framework to avoid this, but haven't had much time to complete this.

As for the color averaging itself, it generally will significantly outpace raw pixel-by-pixel calculations, but there may be ways to improve upon this. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12169560/19679) and the comments that follow for more discussion about this.